# What does the FFmpeg warning "Missing picture in access unit with size x" mean?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I’ve recently updated to the most recent version of ffmpeg and now every time I edit a flv, I always get endless warnings:

> [Null @ 002de180] Missing Missing picture in access unit with size
> xxxx (size varies per file)
>
> [Null @ 002de180] AVC: nal size xxxx (size also varies per
> file)
>
> .....
>
> ...

I’ve checked other versions too and it seems like any version above 2.1.4 will start giving these warnings.

The command I'm using is `ffmpeg.exe -t 0:03:00 -y -i "C:\test.flv" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "C:\Desktop\newvid.flv"` to cut sections of a video.

Even with these warnings, the output file plays fine and the video seems to be in sync. The file size is also the same as if I edit the vid with ffmpeg 2.1.4. But the versions with these warnings take much longer to encode. Any idea what is happening or what these warnings mean?

Comment: I'm using 3.2 and can't replicate your problem. `AVC: nal size xxxx` would indicate to me that it's actually a H.264 codec but FLV should be vp6f. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug until version 2.4.2. It's already solved. For more details see [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4011#no1)

Comment: I just had this one crop up again with build 2022-03-07 from [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/). File seems fine, but it processes slower. I also have a `MB rate (x) > level limit (x)` warning as well, which doesn't seem related.